# Copy data from cell in multiple sheet paste to multiple sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data in cell "C1" in sheet1 and paste to dynamic range "AA:AA" (dynamic base on range "Z") in the same sheet. After that I want it loops to copy from cell "c1" from each sheet and paste to range "AA:AA" each sheet , do like this till finish all sheets, but it is fail.

Error : "Select method of Range class failed" on "Sheets(i).Range("Z21").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Select"

```
Sub copy()
Dim i As Long
Dim s As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count

If Worksheets(i).Range("C1").Value <> "" Then
Sheets(i).Range("Z21").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)).Select = Worksheets(i).Range("C1").Value
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps give [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) a read.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: Sorry sir, my above code does not work so i need help from someone here

Comment: Error : "Select method of Range class failed" on "Sheets(i).Range("Z21").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1).Select"

Comment: What I want : I want to copy data in cell "C1" in sheet1 and paste to dynamic range "AA:AA" (dynamic base on range "Z") in the same sheet1. After that i want it loops to copy data in cell "C1" of another sheet and paste to another sheet too , do like this for the rest sheet.

But it is fail, sir